# Passing values in viewmodel to the post ActionResult in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a property in my *ViewModel* named *"CreatedBy"*. I am populating my ViewModel in a *ActionResult* (get). When I pass the *ViewModel* to the post *ActionResult*, the value of CreatedBy is not included. I have deduced this is caused by the view using a label control instead of a `TextBox`:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
@Model.CreatedBy
```

Do I have to use a `TextBox` on a view if I want to pass a value back to the post method? The *CreatedBy* property should be read-only, I don't want users to be able to change it (hence using a label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Hidden Field` in your form.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy);
```

In Order to `Post` this Value to your *Action Method*, which is in a *Label Control*, you can use `Hidden Field`.

Comment: I get it now. Using @Model.CreatedBy will still display the value on the view, which I want. Thanks!

Comment: @steveareeno : In Order to `Post` this Value to your *Action Method*, which is in a `Label` Control. You can use `Hidden` Field.

Comment: Right. I still wanted the value to display on the view though, but what I didn't realize was that @Model.CreatedBy was already doing this, so using a hidden input wouldn't affect my being able to display the value. Thanks again.